# Pandas compare multiple columns to a specific column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like this:

```
Product_ID Store_1_qty Store_2_qty Store_3_qty
A          10          20          10
B          10          10          10
C          10          10          20
```

I want to add one more column which says 'true' or 'false' if column Store_2_qty, Store_3_qty are both equal to Store_1_qty. However sometimes extra columns like Store_4_qty, Store_5_qty are added, for which again I need to compare all columns to Store_1_qty

I tried this, but it is returning all False in last column

```
result['match'] = np.where(result.iloc[:, 1] == result.iloc[:, :1].all(1), 'True', 'False')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Product_ID` is column use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html), also you can compare all columns with first `Store` column:

```
result['match'] = (result.iloc[:, 1:].eq(result.iloc[:, 1], axis=0)).all(1)
```

Comment: `result['match'] = (result.iloc[:, 1:].eq(result.iloc[:, 1], axis=0)).all(1)` Worked for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly all you need to do is test for uniqueness of you df entries:

```
# Assuming Product_ID is NOT your index:
df['match'] = df.iloc[:,2:].nunique(axis=1) == 1

# If Product_ID is your index it simplifies to:
df['match'] = df.nunique(axis=1) == 1
```

Result:

```
  Product_ID  Store_1_qty  Store_2_qty  Store_3_qty  match
0          A           10           20           10  False
1          B           10           10           10   True
2          C           10           10           20  False
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an attempt. @jezrael's solution is better

```
df['match'] = df[['Store_2_qty', 'Store_3_qty']].eq(df['Store_1_qty'],axis=0).all(1)
```

Output:

```
  Product_ID  Store_1_qty  Store_2_qty  Store_3_qty  match
0          A           10           20           10  False
1          B           10           10           10   True
2          C           10           10           20  False
```

Comment: Actually in my case other columns like store_4_qty, 5, 6 etc can get added depending on data, that's why i needed something that could compare all columns, without me needing to edit the code.

Comment: Completely understood. That's why I mentioned @jezrael's solution is better